# How to loop for a specific amount

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

I am writing a program that would iterate through a sequence of characters, where every 4 counts would add the iterated 4 characters into a char array which means that it must be able to constantly be updating every 4 counts.

For example,

The sequence:
`char sequence[32] = "qRiM1uOtGgXl5yuNPJwKo4+bAdQuPUbr";`

I want a loop that would be able to get every four characters, which in this case the first 4 characters is **"qRiM"**.

Then I would want it to be stored in a char array:
`char test[4];` (This must be able to print qRiM)

Then when 4 counts has been done then the cycle would repeat where the next 4 characters would be **"1uOt"**

I've tried to attempt this but it would only print out qRiM and that the test[4] array is not updating.

```
int count_steps = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    // Adds a character from a sequence into the test array until 4
    while(count_steps < 4) {
        test[i] = sequence[i];
        count_steps++;
    }
    // Checks if four counts has been done
    if (count_steps == 4) {
        //decoder(test, decoded_test);

        // Prints out the four characters
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%c\n", test[j]);
        }
        // Resets back to 0
        count_steps = 0;
    }
    else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: use i*4 as the index into sequence. That will get every fourth entry

Comment: You're using `i` (max value of 31) as an index into the `test` array which is only 4 bytes long. When `i` is 5, it writes to `test[5]`, which is undefined behavior. Even assuming it writes into the byte after the byte after `test[3]`, though, you'll never see that when you print out `test[0]` through `test[3]`

Answer (score 0):

With details explaination from torstenvl, you can rewrite code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    test[i%4] = sequence[i];

    if ((i+1) % 4 == 0) {
        printf("\n");
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%c\n", test[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    test[i] = sequence[i];
```

This line assigns the ith entry in test to the ith entry in sequence. But test only has 4 entries, so on the second iteration, you are writing to `test[4]` throught `test[7]`. You need to use `count_steps` as the index in test.

You also need to add `count_steps` to `i` when accessing sequence so that the correct index in sequence is set in test.

And since you're adding processing 4 characters in each iteration of the for loop, you need to increment `i` by `4`, not by 1

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gr7fGq334)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i += 4/* increment by 4 */) {
    // Adds a character from a sequence into the test array until 4
    while(count_steps < 4) {
        test[count_steps] = sequence[i + count_steps]; // use count_steps as index in test and offset in sequence
        count_steps++;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Second iteration writes to `test[4]` through `test[7]` -- C indexes start at 0.